# Launching kernels... freezes

Tags: front-end, kernel, scripting

I'm running a *Mathematica* script on a remote machine (via ssh connection). I log on the machine and I execute `math -script algorithm.m` and this message appears

> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.
>   Launching kernels...

I think the message of the `FrontEndObject` is only a warning and it's not a particular issue. My problem is that this computation takes 20 seconds and outputs a *.txt* file but the message `Launching kernels...` etc stays forever until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. At that point I can see again my command prompt and, indeed, I find that the output is there and it's been there for minutes.

Any clue?

**Edit:**

The problem is not the Warning of the FrontEnd Object (for which I solved the issue), the problem is the fact that the line `Launching Kernels...` stays forever and I don't get to have the command prompt back.

My program consists simply on a function GeneticAlgorithm[x1_, x_2, x_3] that has already been used multiple times in my group by other phd students and it works. I added just two lines to run the program on a remote machine, namely:

`Export["prova.txt", Timing[GeneticAlgorithm[x1,x2,x3]]];
Print["ciao"];`

So basically my program is:

`GeneticAlgorithm[x1_, x_2, x_3] :=*definition of the function*
Export["prova.txt", Timing[GeneticAlgorithm[x1,x2,x3]]];
Print["ciao"];`

As I run the program, the output prova.txt is created and the line "ciao" appears on the terminal. But nothing else happens, and I don't get my command prompt back. I tried to add `Exit[]`or `Quit[]`to the end of my program but the problem remains.

Comment: The most common operation that requires a front end is `Export` (only with certain formats, but always with graphics).  Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136574/12

Comment: The problem is not the front end (indeed, I found the graphical object and I removed it, thanks Szabolcs). The problem is the fact that the line `Launching kernels...`stays forever and I don't get the command line back. Even if the evaluation is finished. I tried to add End[] to my program but it didn't work. I will modify my question to be more clear and to better highlight my issue

Comment: [You need to provide a complete minimal example then](http://sscce.org/) ... otherwise people have no chance at guessing what is going on. Also, if you do not know what a command does, do not add it to your program at random. `End[]` has no place here (see documentation for what it does).

Comment: Try `math -initfile ...` perhaps